# Azure API gateway not passing the cookie to the apis

Tags: api, azure, api-gateway

### **Scenario**

API gateway : www.testweb.com

### **Actual APIs**

- Authentication api : auth.organization.com
- Data api 1: data1.organization.com
- Data api 2: data2.organization.com

### **API gateway configuration**

- www.testweb.com/auth --> auth.organization.com
- www.testweb.com/data1 --> data1.organization.com
- www.testweb.com/data2 --> data2.organization.com

The intent is to generate cookie from the **auth.organization.com** and use it for **data1.organization.com** and **data2.organization.com** apis.

It appears that the cookie is not passed through to the Actual API by the API gateway.

[The cookie is passed to auth.organization.com]

Comment: How have you set the cookie domain? It should be set as organization.com since you want it to be available to all subdomains of that I guess? Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies

Comment: Checked. Does not seem to be the issue. I have a test env that is working accordingly it seems. I'll try to check the differences in two setups. Thx juunas

Comment: Yeah, no problem. You can check with the browser devtools what the cookie's setup is. If the domain is set correctly (and remember it must be set explicitly by the server), the browser should send it to the other domains too.